# Testing window with renderHooks

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have this custom hook:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'

const useBeforeUnload = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleBeforeUnload = ev => {
      console.log('Test')
    }

    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload)

    return () => window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload)
  }, [])
}

export default useBeforeUnload
```

and I'm trying to get a simple test to work that checks to see if `window.addEventListener` is called:

```
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks'
import useBeforeUnload from './useBeforeUnload'

const spy = jest.fn()

delete window.addEventListener
window.addEventListener = spy

describe('useBeforeUnload', () => {
  describe('When the hook is initialised', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      renderHook(() => useBeforeUnload())
    })

    test('It should register the correct event listener', () => {
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    })
  })
})
```

but it always fails saying that the listener was called 6 times???

[image]

Comment: Never use `=` to assign a spy to a method, this is a bad practice. Use jest.spyOn and do a cleanup between tests. . From now it looks like it's called in other tests and results in test cross-contamination, and this cannot be reproduced by the code you posted which contains only 1 test.

Comment: @EstusFlask You are correct in that it is bad practice to do this instead of spyOn. However, this can be reproduced even with spyOn and the code attached to the question IS enough to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because react-dom is also adding event handlers (for the error event) and these are the handlers that increase your number of calls

One thing you could do is to assert against what you want it to add rather than how many times

```
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith("beforeunload",expect.anything());
```

Comment: could you please help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69113147/test-when-page-beforeonload-in-reactjs