# Test when page beforeonload in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I have a custom hook which check when the page is reloaded and the tab is closed.

```js
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

const useUnload = fn => {
  const cb = useRef(fn); 

  useEffect(() => {
    cb.current = fn;
  }, [fn]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const onUnload = (...args) => cb.current?.(...args);

    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", onUnload);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", onUnload);
  }, []);
};

export default useUnload;
```

How to use:

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  useUnload(e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = '';
  });

  return (
    <div>
      my component ...
    </div>
  );
};
```

Basically when the page is reloaded, url is changed or the tab is closed, appears a modal window which ask you if you want to leave the page. I need to test this hook using enzyme and jest.

```js
import { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import { useUnload } from '../useUnload';

const HookWrapper = ({ hook }) => {
    return <React.Component>{hook}</React.Component>;
};

describe('useUnload', () => {
  it('should render', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <HookWrapper
        hook={() =>
          useUnload((e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.returnValue = '';
          })
        }
      />,
    );
    console.log(wrapper.debug())
  });
});
```

But i get error: `Component(...): No` render`method found on the returned component instance: you may have forgotten to define`render`.`. 
 Who can help testing this hook?

Answer (score 1):

The error you encountered is caused by your implementation of HookWrapper

React.Component is not something you should use in JSX and as such does not have a render method, just as the error message suggests.

What you probably wanted was React.Fragment, or <></> for short
test the hook's functionality

Note that you also usually don't use hooks in the way you used it in the hook wrapper

If you write your hook wrapper like this, it will work and your test will pass:

```
const HookWrapper = ({ hook }) => {
    hook();
    return <></>;
};
```

Be aware that the test you provided does not actually test the functionality of the hook.

Comment: could you help please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69523149/jest-spy-on-does-not-call-the-method-in-react-js