# Jest spy.On() does not call the method in React Js

Tags: jestjs

I write a test for a method:

```js
const methods = {
  run: (name) => {
    console.log('run');
    return name;
  }
}
```

Using `const testMethod = jest.spyOn(methods, 'run').mockResolvedValue({});`, the console.log('run') is not triggered, but if i write: `const testMethod = jest.spyOn(methods, 'run');`, the console.log() is triggered. 
 Why in the first case the console.log() is not triggered and how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `mockResolvedValue`, you are replacing your function with a stub. As the purpose of a stub is not to execute the real implementation of the function but just to return a fictitious value, this behavior is normal.

```
jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({})
```

is equivalent to:

```
jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({}));
```

https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockresolvedvaluevalue

**Update:**

If you want to verify if your function is called and if it returned a specific value, then:

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(methods, 'run');

const myName = 'John Doe';

// Call the method...

expect(spy).toBeCalled();
expect(spy).toHaveReturnedWith(myName);
```

Comment: how to avoid the issue in my case? I need to execute the function wit a specific value.

Comment: Try something like this `const run = methods.run;

    const testMethod = jest.spyOn(methods, 'run').mockImplementation(() => {
      run();
      return { returnValue: 100 };
    });`

Comment: I think I do not really understand your goal.

Comment: Do you want to call your method with specific args ? Or to call it and return a specific value ?

Comment: i want to test if my method is called and also if it returns a specific value. I changed my function above. Could you help?

Comment: I've edited my answer, check if it helps.

Comment: could you help please here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69538543/javascript-mock-a-variable-inside-a-method